# Return list of String using jdbctemplate , preparedstatement

Tags: spring-boot, prepared-statement, postgresql-9.1, jdbctemplate

When I try to retrieve list of Strings as follows, I am getting null/blank values in the resultset.

```
usernames =  sJdbcTemplate.query( new PreparedStatementCreator() {

        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select username from testdb.users"); 


            return preparedStatement;
        }
    }, new ResultSetExtractorAll<String>(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<String>(String.class)));
```

`ResultSetExtractorAll` - is applicable for the custom (pojo / entity) classes as well which I maintain in the application.

I am getting the List of String when I execute the following, but this is not what I am looking for

```
sJdbcTemplate.queryForList("select username from testdb.users", String.class);
```

Could somebody help me out?